# Smart looping over lists using | in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, combinations

I am trying to build a logic sentence (such that only m propositions out of n propositions can be true) with a double loop, but get confused by the "|" token. I cannot find its precise meaning on Hoogle. The select gives a list of lists, a list of indexes that can be selected. With the indexes i want to build a conjunction of positive "selected" propositions and negative "non-selected" propositions. What am i doing wrong with the following code?

```
genXorM :: Int -> Int -> Form 
genXorM n m = Disj [Conj [Neg $ PrpF $ P x, PrpF $ P y] | z <- select, y <- [0 .. n] \\ z, x <- z]  where
  select = combinations m [0 .. n]
```

Comment: Try `[x*x | x <- [1..10]]`. Do you understand the `|` token now?

Comment: `|`, in this context, is part of *list comprehension* syntax, so you should search for that. In other contexts, it can be used for *guards*, so you can look for info on that too. In either case, it should be pronounced "such that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
genXorM :: Int -> Int -> Form 
genXorM n m = Disj [Conj [Neg $ PrpF $ P x, PrpF $ P y] | z <- select, y <- [0 .. n] \\ z, x <- z]  where
  select = combinations m [0 .. n]
```

You have a “triple loop” here. It says:

- For every combination *z* of *m* propositions:

  - For every proposition *y* not in *z*:

    - For every proposition *x* in *z*:

      - Produce the formula ¬*x* ∧ *y*

If I understand correctly that you want a conjunction of all the selected propositions *x* with the negation of all the non-selected ones *y*, that could be written with list comprehensions like this:

```
genXorM :: Int -> Int -> Form 
genXorM n m = Disj
  [ Conj
    ([PrpF (P p) | p <- x]
      ++ [Neg (PrpF (P n)) | n <- y])
  | x <- select
  , let y = [0 .. n] \\ x
  ]
  where
    select = combinations m [0 .. n]
```

Or without them, for example, using `map` and some helper functions to break down the problem into smaller pieces:

```
genXorM n m = Disj (map conjoin selected)
  where
    selected = combinations m [0 .. n]
    conjoin z = Conj (map positive z ++ map negative (complement z))
    positive = PrpF . P
    negative = Neg . positive
    complement x = [0 .. n] \\ x
```